# how do i pass a single char value to a string variable after increment from a linQ record data

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

```
internal char SubMeasurement = 'a';
internal string GetLast;  

    private void CreateSub() 
            {            
                SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext();
                try
                {
                    var CheckRecordSub = SFC.Systems_SettingsMeasurements.Where(r => r.RelationData == txtNO.Text)
                        .Select(t => new { CODE = t.No });
                    int count = 0; int total = 0;             
                    string[] row = new string[CheckRecordSub.Count()];
                    foreach (var r in CheckRecordSub)
                    {
                        row[count] = r.CODE;
                        GetLast = r.CODE;
                        count++;
                        total = count;
                    }
                    if (txtNO.Text == GetLast)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(SubMeasurement.ToString()); <-- Msg Box doesn't Work
                    }
                    else 
                    {                    
                        SubMeasurement = Convert.ToChar(GetLast);
                        SubMeasurement++; <-- Error
                        MessageBox.Show(SubMeasurement.ToString()); <-- Msg Box doesn't Work
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
```

I have a record data which is when a user tries to pick a "Sub" option instead of a "Header" the process tries to check for a record last sub record and takes that record put it in a char and increment it and then place it back to a string variable at this code i just use messagebox to check if i get the last record and if it increments it if its a Header it just take the default value of the "SubMeasurement" 'a' for a start. but its not working that way please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's error of course it is. Because char can not increase in normal, if you really need it let try some kind of difference:

```
int asciiCode = ((int)SubMeasurement) + 1;
SubMeasurement = (char)asciiCode;
```

Comment: thank you sir but what if then i try to put it into string variable after the increment.

Comment: Yes sure! Now your SubMeasurement is 'b'

Comment: just to add why is it when i try to use this "char SubMeasurement = Convert.toChar(GetLast);" it doesn't work? is my passing of a value correct like this?

Comment: No no! String is a list of char, you can't do that. You must use like this 'char[] a = b.ToCharArray();'

Comment: what if its a single char like. "GetLast = 'a'" <-- how can i put this to a string variable "string GetLetter" ??

Comment: Just do this: "string GetLetter = GetLast.toString();"

Comment: and ok last thing how about if a string GetLetter = "a" be place its value to a Char GetLast how do i do that please help?

Comment: Ok just do this "char GetLast = GetLetter.ToCharArray()[0];"